# read binary thru php and save it thru exec over shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, unix

How to save binary content through shell ?

I wrote not working example

```
$f = file_get_contents("my.exe");
exec("echo $f > new.exe");
```

Comment: Use php functions to open a new file and write $f into it.  PHP has file manipulation functions just for that.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe someone in future will want this todo, php with nobody/www-data can write to root files

```
function my_file_put_contents($f, $content){
    $rand_file = "/tmp/my_tmp_".uniqid('', true);
    file_put_contents($rand_file, $content);
    exec('sudo cp '.escapeshellarg($rand_file).' '.escapeshellarg($f).' && rm '.escapeshellarg($rand_file));
}
```

then edit /etc/sudoers with visudo

```
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp
```